# safari textfield background color wont change

Tags: css, safari

```
#searchInput {
    width: 82px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -273px;
    left: -205px;
    color: #FF7F27;
    font-size: 85%;
    background: transparent;
```

}

the code above does not turn the textfied background color to transparent in safari. I tried about opacity but that just makes the text and font dissappear at the same. this problems happens in one fo the other browser ive tested with.

Comment: Which version of Safari do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove the default styling and allowthe new css properties,so you need to change the -webkit-appearance property.

```
  #searchInput {
              width: 82px;
              height: 40px;
              margin: 0;
              border: 0;
              position: relative;
              top: -273px;
              left: -205px;
              color: #FF7F27;
              font-size: 85%;
              background: transparent;
              -webkit-appearance: none;/* this should Work */
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [generating a transparent background](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e5799+0,7db9e8+100&0.01+0,0+100;Custom) then apply it using the generated code at that url, like:

```
#searchInput
{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}
```